# App indicator not showing properly (Sigram)

Tags: indicator, location

I've installed Sigram and the app indicator is showing at the left top corner of the "panel" as you can see in [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNz0k.jpg):

[image]

I'm looking for some info but I can't find anything related with this problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps log a bug directly with the developers [here](https://github.com/sialan-labs/sigram/issues).

Answer (score -1):

In my case installing libappindicator1 fixed it.

`sudo apt-get install libappindicator1`

Comment: Thak you, it worked too for me! :D